# installed desktop environment not showing at login screen

Tags: desktop-environments, login-screen

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu Gnome, and wanted to add Unity as an alternate desktop environment. I tried to accomplish this via Ubuntu Software Center, but the fact is that the option doesn't show up in the menu at login. Not even after restarting the system. Checked if unity was indeed installed in synaptic, apparently it is. So, how can I have the Unity option available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad! If you want to install unity you don't have to pick the package with that same name, but the one that reads ubuntu-desktop. If I am not mistaken, unity package depends on ubuntu-desktop.